# How to Concatenate an ArrayList of MediaSources in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, kotlin, return-type, exoplayer2.x

I would like to know how to be able to play more than two songs back to back in ExoPlayer using MediaSources I have in an ArrayList.

I can use `ConcatenatingMediaSource` to be able to play two songs back to back, but I have to load them into this fundtion as separate paramters. I do not want to do this for a whole list of songs. I have tried to find an answer to this and seem to have some fundemental misunderstanding as I can't seem to replicate the efforts of others in other StackOverflow questions or blogs etc. (Many blogs show the simple two media source playlist as in the ExoPlayer docs).

This code is for context:

```
    private fun prepareExoPlayer(songs: ListSongs) {
        val uris = parseUris(songs)
        val mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uris)
        applyAudioAttributes()
        simpleExoPlayer!!.prepare(mediaSource, false, false)
    }
```

This code is where the issue is:

```
    private fun buildMediaSource(uris: ArrayList<Uri>): MediaSource {
        val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "MusicPlayer")
        val defaultMediaSource = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, userAgent)
        val progressiveMediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(defaultMediaSource)
        val mediaSources = ArrayList<MediaSource>()

        for (uri in uris) {
            mediaSources.add(progressiveMediaSource.createMediaSource(uri))
        }

        return if (mediaSources.size == 1) {
            mediaSources[0]
        } else {
            val concatenatingMediaSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource()
            concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSources(mediaSources)
//            ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources[0], mediaSources[1])
        }
    }
```

In the else statement I get a failure as the return type is not a MediaSource, but a Unit. However, the commented code on the last line works fine. How do I modify the 2nd and 3rd last line to be able to play my list of songs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I just found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svdq1BWl4r8

Turns out `prepare` for ExoPlayer does not have to have a `MediaSource` as a parameter, but can have a `ConcatenatingMediaSource` as a parameter as well. These aren't the same but are both accepted by the `prepare` function.

It's also worth noting that `ConcatenatingMediaSource` can recieve a single `MediaSource`. This means the `if` statement check on the size of the `MediaSource` `ArrayList` isn't necessary.

The solution is therefore to change the return type of `buildMediaSource` to `ConcatenatingMediaSource` and remove the if statement. Like this:

```
    private fun buildMediaSource(uris: ArrayList<Uri>): ConcatenatingMediaSource {
        val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this, "MusicPlayer")
        val defaultMediaSource = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, userAgent)
        val progressiveMediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(defaultMediaSource)
        val mediaSources = ArrayList<MediaSource>()

        for (uri in uris) {
            mediaSources.add(progressiveMediaSource.createMediaSource(uri))
        }

        val concatenatingMediaSource = ConcatenatingMediaSource()
            concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSources(mediaSources)

        return concatenatingMediaSource
    }
```